# can I reset the windows 7 public firewall profile defaults?

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall

suppose I change something in the public firewall profile. (whether in the "windows firewall with advanced security screen" or in the "allow programs to communicate through windows firewall" screen

can I reset the windows 7 public firewall profile defaults?

if so, how?

Also I noticed that file and printer sharing is enabled.. that seems a little strange to me, as public profile is meant to be restrictive for a public place like an internet cafe. Though I think enabled is the default. (added- it's not default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Actions pane there is a `Restore Default Policy` link that should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, and lo and behold, FnP sharing now disabled in public profile. default.

Comment: Glad to help...